# Disable online ordering facility from opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

I want to disable online ordering facility from open cart. I want to disable following features

- My account
- Wish List
- shopping cart
- Checkout

  How to do those things? The reason is the disable it, Now is the very beginning of the web site. Latter we'll add those features too

Answer (score 0):

You can always disable them with CSS? since you want to re-enable them later

for instance

In my store the cart button is `.product-grid .cart .button`

So just open your stylesheet.css file in `catalog/view/theme/YOURTHEME/stylesheet/stylesheet.css`

```
.product-grid .cart .button{
 display:none
}
```

make sure you put it in the bottom of your stylesheet or it might not work since css looks for the last style

If you are not sure how to find all that info

Right click on your **cart button** inspect element
On the right side you will see a box **Styles**
Under it you will see the style like: `.product-grid .cart .button`
or something else depending on your theme